# Lost some reputation over night

Tags: discussion, reputation

Last night I had 2,873 reputation and this morning I had 2,868 reputation, I lost 5 reputation. I checked my [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3204827/howlin?tab=reputation) tab, but it doesn't show any rep lost. I checked the https://stackoverflow.com/reputation page as well and I can't see it. I lost 2 rep about a week or two ago as well and I didn't get any notification as to why I lost it then as well. 
I don't mind losing rep if there is a reason for it (poor answer/question etc.), but I'm wondering why I didn't see any notification this time?

Comment: You have "show removed posts" enabled at the bottom of your reputation tab?

Comment: Did you check the 'show removed posts' checkbox at the bottom of the reputation page?

Comment: Do you have the "show removed posts" box checked at the bottom of your reputation history? It shows that you lost 4 reputation for two deleted posts you'd had suggested edits on.

Comment: ^^ what those 3 say

Comment: What Bart said. Also, what Bart said.

Comment: Also, it's only 5 (well actually 4) points. Don't sweat it. You're already up more than that on the day so in the grand scheme of things it's nothing to get worried about.

Comment: I thought I did have that box ticked, but I guess I didn't. I see them now, thanks :)

Comment: I'm sure you're not Robinson Crusoe in that respect. Or Robina, for that matter...